# How to store a function and call it later in QML JavaScript

Tags: qt, qml

Here is part of code:

```
Repeater{
    model: [["Text A", function(){console.log("hello A")}],
            ["Text B", function(){console.log("hello B")}],
            ["Text C", function(){console.log("hello C")}],
            ["Text D", function(){console.log("hello D")}]]
    delegate: Button{
        text: modelData[0]
        onClicked: modelData[1](); // Type Error
    }
}
```

I want give different behavior for each button. I think it's supposed to be same as native JavaScript.

```
var func = function(){
  //...
}
func();
```

How to do this in QML JavaScript?

BTW, now my solution is:

```
Repeater{
    model: ["Text A",
            "Text B",
            "Text C",
            "Text D"]
    delegate: Button{
        text: modelData
        onClicked: {
           switch(index)
           {
              cast 0:
                console.log("hello A")
                break;
              cast 1:
                console.log("hello B")
                break;
              cast 2:
                console.log("hello C")
                break;
              cast 3:
                console.log("hello D")
                break;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me better?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want store lambda function's function pointer as variable into an array(model of Repeator) at the moment of component(Button) creation. Then call stored function pointer if Button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me, it just won't get to the function through the model interface. Or maybe a design limitation. As far as the function is concerned, it is `undefined`.

You could work around it like this:

```
  property var mod :
   [["Text A", function(){console.log("hello A")}],
    ["Text B", function(){console.log("hello B")}],
    ["Text C", function(){console.log("hello C")}],
    ["Text D", function(){console.log("hello D")}]]

  Column {
    Repeater {
      id: rep
      model: mod
      delegate: Button {
        text: modelData[0]
        onClicked: mod[index][1]()
      }
    }
  }
```